# Configurable Joint: how to create a FixedJoint, and Rotating it?

Tags: unity, joints

I have 2 rigidbody, in 2d view, non kinematic, and with no gravity, and want to connect them with a Configurable joint. I don't want the joint to be spring (I want the same distance always). But I would like to move the blue object left / right (rotating it around the red one)

How can I setup my Configurable Joint ?

Thanks you !

[image]

Comment: This looks like you could accomplish it more simply with a Hinge Joint. Is there a particular reason you want to use a Configurable Joint instead?

Comment: Mmm I didn't know that, I'll try it on.